# exclude @Entity from persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using persistence.xml in hibernate

However, I am some @Entity in the classpath which I don't them to be part of persistence.xml.

in the documentation

> class The class element specifies a
>   fully qualified class name that you
>   will map. By default all properly
>   annotated classes and all hbm.xml
>   files found inside the archive are
>   added to the persistence unit
>   configuration.

Is there to exclude some entities from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible afaik. But don't worry about that - if you don't use these classes they will not bother you, apart from their metadata being loaded by the session factory.

**Update:** `hbm2ddl` tools (like ant) have the `excludes` option. I don't know how you are using it, so search for options there.

Apart from this, you can manually list all classes in `persistence.xml` and use:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: It DOES bother me since I use hbm2dll create for part of them.